# wordpress do not duplicate post

Tags: wordpress, duplicates

I know how to use few loops without duplicate posts.

But My question is:

Suppose I have two loops, each two loop shows 1 post only, both of them have the same newest post. if I use the code below, the duplicate post will be not shown at the second loop, but it is also stop to continue with the next post. how to solve it. million thx!

code:

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('cat=1,2&posts_per_page=1');
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
    $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; ?>
    first loop
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php query_posts('cat=10&posts_per_page=1'); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); if (in_array($post->ID, $do_not_duplicate)) continue;?>
    second loop
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to clean the example up a little bit:

You have `$do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;`, assuming your variable is the **String** post_id, then you check `if (in_array($post->ID, $do_not_duplicate)) continue;`

At this point `$do_not_duplicate` is **NOT** an array().

If you want to store an array(), try this: `$do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID;`, then you can perform your current check.